# Is it semantically right to call a post excerpt an <article>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a list of blog excerpts, is it OK to call each an `article` or should I use list and divs instead?

```
<article class="post-excerpt body-font">
    <header>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="post.html">At Day's End</a></h2>
        <p><time datetime="2010-03-04T16:31:24+02:00">March 2010</time> &sdot; This post is about <a href="#">Poetry</a>, <a href="#">Creativity</a> and <a href="#">Myself</a></p>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <p>And at day's end,<br />
        Laying on my back.</p>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p><a href="post.html">Read more &rArr;</a></p>
    </footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think [`article`(w3 spec)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-article-element.html#the-article-element) is appropriate in this case.

> The article element represents a self-contained composition in a
>   document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle,
>   independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This
>   could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry,
>   a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any
>   other independent item of content.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times blog excerpts are not that clear as you presented it (you posted the perfect scenario), so I wouldn't take as a rule to use article for any blog excerpts.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing what steveax says, that is an ideal example of where `article` should be used, probably one of the clearest!